# Simple approximation to a series of infinite terms

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is it possible to approximate the following series in a similar way to the Neumann series for example where the formula is the limit of the series as the terms approach infinity:
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}a^ib^j
$$
$a$ and $b$ are both fractions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am not wrong, this is simply a geometric series.
\begin{align}
\sum_{i \ge 0} \sum_{j \ge 0}a^i b^j
&=\sum_{i \ge 0} a^i \sum_{j \ge 0}b^j\\
&= \sum_{i \ge 0} \frac{a^i}{1-b}\\
&=\frac{1}{(1-a)(1-b)}
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Try $\displaystyle\left(\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a^i\right)\left( \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}b^j\right)$ as the product of geometric series if $-1 \lt a \lt 1$ and $-1 \lt b \lt 1$.

You should not need an approximation.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\sum_{i=0}^\infty \left( \underbrace{\sum_{j=0}^\infty a^ib^j}_\text{Let's work with this inside part first.} \right)
$$
$$
\sum_{j=0}^\infty ( a^ib^j)
$$
As $j$ goes from $0$ to $\infty$, $i$ does not change, so $a^i$ does not change.  Therefore this sum is
$$
a^i \sum_{j=0}^\infty b^j.
$$
Now we have
$$
\sum_{i=0}^\infty \left( a^i \sum_{j=0}^\infty b^j \right).
$$
As $i$ goes from $0$ to $\infty$, the factor $\sum_{j=0}^\infty b^j$ does not change.  Therefore it can be pulled out of the outer sum in the same way.